# How to access env variables from react / how to inject env variables to react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, environment-variables

I tried adding this to the plugins section of my webpack config, but that makes the build unusable. I am not using cra.

```js
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': dotenv.parsed,
})
```

Changing this to

```js
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'APP_URL': dotenv.APP_URL,
})
```

Didn't help -> `APP_URL` stayed undefined in the app :(

I did not find another syntax for injecting variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `DefinePlugin` just replaces text and does not introduce global variables.

So it needs quotes around the value so the replacement makes a correct JS syntax:

```
'APP_URL': `"${dotenv.APP_URL}"`,
```

Here's my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

const dotenv = { APP_URL: 'http://localhost/app' };

module.exports = [
    {
        entry: './src/test.js',
        mode: 'production',
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'APP_URL': `"${dotenv.APP_URL}"`,
            })
        ]
    }
]
```

**Don't forget to put quotes around the values or use `JSON.stringify`**

And here's `./src/test.js` file:

```
const url = APP_URL;
console.log(url);
```

Development build outputs eval statement with the whole code and replacement:

```
/***/ "./src/test.js":
/*!*********************!*\
  !*** ./src/test.js ***!
  \*********************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

eval("const url = \"http://localhost/app\";\nconsole.log(url);\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./src/test.js?");

/***/ })

/******/ });
```

While production build keeps just resulting `console.log` call:

```
[function(e,t){console.log("http://localhost/app")}]
```

Comment: I forgot to use 'JSON.stringify`. It is weird because you need to stringify a string ... :D

(Added that in an edit, you can update your answer and I'll accept it :) )

Comment: thanks. yep JSON.stringify() would be the safest option